# Why is my program waiting for the popup to close?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, user32

i am trying to work into the automation of another programs using mthe methods of user32.dll in my C# project. I created a small test program to automatically enter text inputs and click a button. Once the button is clicked, a popup appears that can be closed with the 'yes' button.

However, as soon as the popup opens, my program is waiting for it to close until it continues running its code. (I have to click the button manually)

How do i keep the code running to access the popup window?

```
Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to continue.");

Console.ReadLine();
identifyProcess();
RemoteMethods.updateWindows(_MainWnd);
IntPtr saveButton = RemoteMethods.GetChildWindow(RemoteMethods.GetIndexByTitle(_MainWnd, "Save")[0]);
IntPtr titleTF = RemoteMethods.GetChildWindow(3);
IntPtr nameTF = RemoteMethods.GetChildWindow(5);
IntPtr streetTF = RemoteMethods.GetChildWindow(1);

//Replacing Text

RemoteMethods.SendMessage(titleTF, RemoteMethods.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "Mr.");
RemoteMethods.SendMessage(nameTF, RemoteMethods.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "Berg");
RemoteMethods.SendMessage(streetTF, RemoteMethods.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "Fountainally 3.");

RemoteMethods.ClickButton(saveButton);

//Popup appears here
//But the program only continues after i click 'Yes' manually.

Console.WriteLine("Test");
IntPtr nW = RemoteMethods.GetLastActivePopup(_MainWnd);
RemoteMethods.updateWindows(nW);
IntPtr yesButton = RemoteMethods.GetChildWindow(RemoteMethods.GetIndexByTitle(nW, "Yes")[0]);

RemoteMethods.ClickButton(yesButton);
```

Here is the RemoteMethods class:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19xtvq6ep8ICKY4WZqY0BBv8schnhzfqs/view?usp=sharing

[image: This is what happens.]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, yes the code stops right before ```Console.WriteLine()``` It is very weird.

Comment: since nW is only called after i close the popup, it ready the IntPtr of the main Window instead and than reads all the elements inside instead of the popup. The yes button throws an out of bounds exception because it can not be found in the main Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SendMessage()` will wait until the message was processed, i.e. the method handler of the save button has run to its end. This will not be the case if that handler opens another window and waits for user input (as in your case).

Use [`SendNotifyMessage()`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/sendnotifymessage.html) or [`Postmessage()`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/PostMessage.html) instead. They are similar, but `SendNotifyMessage()` will give the message a higher priority than `PostMessage()`. Both methods work in an asynchronous way, i.e. they will return immediately.

This in turn means, that you might need to retry querying the next window, since it might not be shown yet directly when the method returned.

Comment: Thank you so much! it was exactly that.
I didnt know that, this is very useful information.
Now it keeps running without a problem :)